# Why would this exemple only works with a breakpoint

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, kbhit

I'm creating a basic console application in C/C++.

In the following example I'm repeatedly writing some char to the console with a 50ms delay and I want it to exit the program when I hit a key.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int PauseRet(int iDuree) {
    unsigned int uiTemps = GetTickCount();
    int iVal = 0;
    do {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            iVal = _getch();
        }

    } while ((GetTickCount() - uiTemps) < (unsigned int)iDuree);

    return iVal;
}

int main()
{
    char c = 0;
    int iTempo = 50;
    while (true) {


        putchar('a');

        c = PauseRet(iTempo);


        if (c) {

            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that in my project it goes into the condition `if(c){...` only when I put a break point here:

```
    if (_kbhit()) {
        <BREAKPOINT> iVal = _getch();
    }
```

I'm using visual studio 2017.

I've tried this code on another PC in a new project and I didn't had any problem

I believe this has something to do with my project settings.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: @StereoBucket I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Can you provide specific build? Or better yet, under project/properties -> general, what is the SDK version.

Comment: @StereoBucket The Windows SDK Version is 10.0.17134.0

Comment: @Tom23, not reproduced in VS 2017 15.9.4 and Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0

Comment: @chronoxor the bug they're experiencing has been fixed in 10.0.17763.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running into a little bug with `_getch()`. On SDK `10.0.17134.0`the bug is that `_getch()` will return the key that was pressed and on the next call return 0.

Without breakpoints, the `_kbhit` might return true more than once, which would put 0 into `c` and your `if(c)` would never pass.
With breakpoints, once you've pressed the key, it would stop there, the key would subsequently be released in time and once you continue from the breakpoint, `_getch()` would return the key that was pressed, and `_kbhit` would no longer return true. Once the loop exits, you will have had a non-zero value in `c`.

To fix this, update your SDK by running the VS 2017 setup again and updating (or downgrading to something before april update) and/or downloading newer SDK or use `_getwch()`

[Relevant MS Dev Community bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247770/-getch-broken-in-vs-157.html). (fixed)

Comment: This seemed to be the problem, updating VS fixed it, thanks!